# Settings Chart series dynamically with sql doesn't show chart when downloaded in png image form using Itextsharp.pdf

Tags: c#, sql, charts

I am new to .net as i am creating chart programatically with series using sql db as  I have two buttons one for search and another for download chart into png image. In search button i am creating chart programatically with series where as the second button is used for downloading chart into png format thats where i am stuck for hours.

search method goes here:

```
 public  void searchdataByCity()
    {
        try
        {
            string abc = locationDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string query = "select max(title),count(title)as counts from indeed where city like '%" + abc + "%'  having count(title) > 1 union select max(title),count(title)as counts from mitula where city like '%" + abc + "%'  having count(title) > 1 union select max(title),count(title)as counts from trovoit where city like '%" + abc + "%'  having count(title) > 1 union select max(title),count(title)as counts from glassdoor where city like '%" + abc + "%'  having count(title) > 1";
            Series series1 = Chart2.Series["Series1"];
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                series1.Points.AddXY(rdr[0].ToString(),rdr[1].ToString());
            }


            con.Close();            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Download button goes here:

```
 protected void DownloadCustomizeData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["fullname"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginForm.aspx");
        }
        else
        {

            download_chartImage(Chart2);
        }
    }
```

and download_chartImage goes here :

```
 private void download_chartImage(Chart chartimg)
    {
        Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, Response.OutputStream);

        Doc.Open();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())

        {

            chartimg.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(memoryStream.GetBuffer());

            img.ScalePercent(75f);

            Doc.Add(img);

            Doc.Close();



            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Chart.pdf");

            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            Response.Write(Doc);

            Response.End();

        }

    }
```

Can anyone help me out that how could I access chart2 object into a download button method to download the chart as png? The code answer will be appreciated.

Comment: do you not want the PDF? should download_chartImage(Chart chartimg) return a PNG to the client instead of a PDF?

Comment: it downloads png into a pdf format. The main problem is how can i access chart2 object into download button as the chart which is downloading is not visible due to this problem.